# Docker - unknown command "run"

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a docker container on an Ubuntu WSL2 instance on Windows 10. Docker version installed in 20.10.17. I have been able to run docker commands and build the image successfully.

The output of docker images:
[image]

When I try to run the container using the command `docker run -p 5000:5000 test` it gives the following error:
[image]

I have never had this issue with docker before and not sure why it thinks it's an npm command. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Why your output speak about npm ?

Comment: That's why I am confused. I was able to build the image but when I use the docker run command it references npm.

Comment: What is your Dockerfile? This seems a problem related to the image and not the command to run Docker. Most likely the image you are trying to run, invokes npm in some way and it has a syntax error

Comment: Ah thanks. That makes sense. I do use some npm commands in my Dockerfile so I will look that over.

Comment: Yeah you were right. The issue was syntax in my Dockerfile. Instead of "run" in the CMD command I had "run,". Thanks!